# What Typescript type is Angular2 event

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

If I have the following button in an html file

```html
<button (click)="doSomething('testing', $event)">Do something</button>
```

Also, in the corresponding component, I have this function

```
doSomething(testString: string, event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log(testString + ': I am doing something');
}
```

Is there a proper type that should be assigned to the `$event` input?
The event parameter itself is an object, BUT if I assign it to a type object, I get an error

> Property 'stopPropogation' does not exist on type object

So, what does Typescript consider the `$event` input?

Comment: `doSomething(testString: string, event: MouseEvent)`

Comment: Eric Martinez: Can you post your comment as an answer?  That cleared up all of the flags I was getting, so I am taking it as correct.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

As suggested by @AlexJ

The event you passed through `$event` is a DOM event, therefore you can use the `EventName` as the type.

In your case this event is a [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent), and the docs says, quoting

> The **MouseEvent** interface represents events that occur due to the user interacting with a pointing device (such as a mouse). Common events using this interface include **click, dblclick, mouseup, mousedown**.

In all those cases you'll get a `MouseEvent`.

Another example : if you have this code

```
<input type="text" (blur)="event($event)"
```

When the event triggers you'll get a [`FocusEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent).

So you can do it really simple, console log the event and you'll see a message similar to this one that'll we have the event name

```
FocusEvent {isTrusted: true, relatedTarget: null, view: Window, detail: 0, which: 0…}
```

You can always visit the docs for a list of existing [Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).

**Edit**

You can also check for TypeScript [`dom.generated.d.ts`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts) with all the typings ported. In your case `stopPropagation()` is part of [`Event`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L3047), extended by `MouseEvent`.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43176930/23118) for a HTMLInputEvent type.

Comment: It should be noted that if the event originates from an Angular component through an `@Output`, typically a component field of type `EventEmitter<T>`, then the type of the `$event` argument is `T`. See https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter.

Comment: eg. `KeyboardEvent` for events like `(keydown)` or `(keypress)`

Answer (score 85):

Some commonly used events and their related names ([MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent), [FocusEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent), [TouchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent), [DragEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DragEvent), [KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent)):

```
| MouseEvent | FocusEvent |  TouchEvent | DragEvent | KeyboardEvent |
|:----------:|:----------:|:-----------:|:---------:|:-------------:|
|    click   |    focus   |  touchstart |    drag   |    keypress   |
|   mouseup  |    blur    |  touchmove  |    drop   |     keyup     |
| mouseleave |   focusin  | touchcancel |  dragend  |    keydown    |
|  mouseover |  focusout  |   touchend  |  dragover |               |
```

The generic [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) is associated to:

- close
- cancel
- **change**
- invalid
- play
- reset
- **scroll**
- scrollend
- select
- **toggle**
- waiting

If you dig in [Typescript's repository, **dom.generated.d.ts** provides a mapping of all global events handlers](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts) (credit goes to [Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35972361/6225838)) in the [***GlobalEventHandlersEventMap*** interface](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/769f2daf712c2cf057259ac5321174702ba0d59e/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L8818):

```
interface GlobalEventHandlersEventMap {
    "abort": UIEvent;
    "animationcancel": AnimationEvent;
    "animationend": AnimationEvent;
    "animationiteration": AnimationEvent;
    "animationstart": AnimationEvent;
    "auxclick": MouseEvent;
    "beforeinput": InputEvent;
    "blur": FocusEvent;
    "cancel": Event;
    "canplay": Event;
    "canplaythrough": Event;
    "change": Event;
    "click": MouseEvent;
    "close": Event;
    "compositionend": CompositionEvent;
    "compositionstart": CompositionEvent;
    "compositionupdate": CompositionEvent;
    "contextmenu": MouseEvent;
    "copy": ClipboardEvent;
    "cuechange": Event;
    "cut": ClipboardEvent;
    "dblclick": MouseEvent;
    "drag": DragEvent;
    "dragend": DragEvent;
    "dragenter": DragEvent;
    "dragleave": DragEvent;
    "dragover": DragEvent;
    "dragstart": DragEvent;
    "drop": DragEvent;
    "durationchange": Event;
    "emptied": Event;
    "ended": Event;
    "error": ErrorEvent;
    "focus": FocusEvent;
    "focusin": FocusEvent;
    "focusout": FocusEvent;
    "formdata": FormDataEvent;
    "gotpointercapture": PointerEvent;
    "input": Event;
    "invalid": Event;
    "keydown": KeyboardEvent;
    "keypress": KeyboardEvent;
    "keyup": KeyboardEvent;
    "load": Event;
    "loadeddata": Event;
    "loadedmetadata": Event;
    "loadstart": Event;
    "lostpointercapture": PointerEvent;
    "mousedown": MouseEvent;
    "mouseenter": MouseEvent;
    "mouseleave": MouseEvent;
    "mousemove": MouseEvent;
    "mouseout": MouseEvent;
    "mouseover": MouseEvent;
    "mouseup": MouseEvent;
    "paste": ClipboardEvent;
    "pause": Event;
    "play": Event;
    "playing": Event;
    "pointercancel": PointerEvent;
    "pointerdown": PointerEvent;
    "pointerenter": PointerEvent;
    "pointerleave": PointerEvent;
    "pointermove": PointerEvent;
    "pointerout": PointerEvent;
    "pointerover": PointerEvent;
    "pointerup": PointerEvent;
    "progress": ProgressEvent;
    "ratechange": Event;
    "reset": Event;
    "resize": UIEvent;
    "scroll": Event;
    "scrollend": Event;
    "securitypolicyviolation": SecurityPolicyViolationEvent;
    "seeked": Event;
    "seeking": Event;
    "select": Event;
    "selectionchange": Event;
    "selectstart": Event;
    "slotchange": Event;
    "stalled": Event;
    "submit": SubmitEvent;
    "suspend": Event;
    "timeupdate": Event;
    "toggle": Event;
    "touchcancel": TouchEvent;
    "touchend": TouchEvent;
    "touchmove": TouchEvent;
    "touchstart": TouchEvent;
    "transitioncancel": TransitionEvent;
    "transitionend": TransitionEvent;
    "transitionrun": TransitionEvent;
    "transitionstart": TransitionEvent;
    "volumechange": Event;
    "waiting": Event;
    "webkitanimationend": Event;
    "webkitanimationiteration": Event;
    "webkitanimationstart": Event;
    "webkittransitionend": Event;
    "wheel": WheelEvent;
}
```

Comment: Exactly the thing I wanted, in the format I wanted it . Thank you CPHPython !

Comment: Glad it helped, thank you for updating the TS link, I also updated the list of handlers.

Comment: This should be the Golden Standard for formatting -- such an incredibly-well formatted and concise answer! ⭐

Comment: The line number has been changed: [L5419](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L5419)

Answer (score 3):

According to official `event` is of type `Object`, also in my case when i typecaste `event` to the Object it does't throw any error, but after reading documentation of angular2 found `event` is of type `EventEmitter` so you can type caste your event into `EventEmitter`

see here is plunkr for the same http://plnkr.co/edit/8HRA3bM0NxXrzBAjWYXc?p=preview

for more info refer here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#event-binding

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers excellently treated the original question and guided me in the right direction.

However, I stumbled upon this page while starting to learn Angular(and front-end) and not having a clear picture of how the mentioned types are documented and maintained. A short reference to additional context:

Both [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) and [`Focus Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent) are part of Mozilla's  [`Web API's`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) specification - the de facto API used by most modern Web Browser for exposing functionality to the JavaScript runtime.

If you are used to a back-end environment like Java, the Web API specification can be viewed as a rough equivalent to the central documentation ([Oracle's Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/) in Java's case) maintained by the language provider plus some reference to third-party APIs.

Unlike Java/C# specifications where the main distributions are guaranteed to fully implement the specs, on the front-end, **every browser provider has the liberty of choosing which parts are supported** - while common events like click will most probably be supported by everything on the markets this is not a guarantee as you dive deeper into more advanced functionalities. However, the Web API's specification documentation does a great job of tracking the support of the major browser by all of its specified features, for example, here the [Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent#browser_compatibility) of the `MouseEvent` can be consulted.

For an excelent introduction to the Web API's, please check the official presentation on [Mozzila's Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Introduction)