# What will be the type for eventdata in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a input box, when I click on it I'll actually send the eventdata of the input box using a function:

```
<input type="text" (click)="show($event)"/>
```

I'm using typescript here to write a function hence I need to assign a type to the function parameter

What will be the type for an event?

Typescript Code :

```
show(eventdata: ?) { }
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35966965/23118.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as you are catching a `click` in your `input` element, the event will most propbably be of the type `MouseEvent`.

You also might want to have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35972361/7579291).

Comment: I don't want to be specific, Can I use Event as the type?

Comment: @Harish I think you can. As `MouseEvent` extends `Event` anyway, it should work.

Comment: @Harish Have a look at [the MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) for further information on Events. Also please accept the answer if it did help you.