# TypeScript: what is the correct "HTML type" for a checkbox input?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have a checkbox in angular2 application. I catch the click event on it and check the `checked` property value.

However, during compilation, `event.target.checked` is not recognize:

```
error TS2339: Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
```

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42066421/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget), I should inform typescript of the type.

**But what is the type of my input ?**  I do not find anything related to checkbox in code completion and `HTMLInputElement` throws the same error.

---

HTML input

```
<input id="ID" formControlName="key" type="checkbox"
                    aria-label="Checkbox for following text input">
```

---

Typescript

```
$("#id").on('click', (event:Event) => {
  if (<WHAT SHOULD BE THERE ?>(event.target).checked) {
    $("#id").prop('checked', false);
  } else {
    $("#id").prop('checked', true);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can refer to 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243308/how-to-check-is-checkbox-is-checked-angular2]. It should be event.checked instead.

Comment: @souravsatyam``checked does not exists on type "Event"``

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis Yes. I though the code was quite explicit about that ^^

Comment: Use (event) => {} instead of (event:Event) => {} and check.

Comment: event type is not Event. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35966965/what-typescript-type-is-angular2-event]

Comment: @souravsatyam Thanks. That was it !

Comment: Explained above.

Comment: If you can create an answer, i'll accept it @souravsatyam

Answer (score -1, accepted):

But what is the type of my input ?

If you are not sure about the type of checkbox event you can use type as **any** which can accept any data in any format.

In the above case instead of event.target.checked there should be event.checked and type definition (event: Event) => {} should be replaced by (event: any) => {}

Answer (score 1):

```
let test: HTMLInputElement;
console.log(test.checked);
```

Works just fine, no errors in my React codebase. check that your typescript is not crashed!